# svn merge from trunk after updating branch makes me the author of lots of file modifications

Tags: svn, version-control, merge

```
cd my/branch
svn up
svn merge my/trunk
svn commit -m 'merged from trunk'
```

then I use

```
svn blame somefile
```

I see some changes not made by me but says its author is me.

My question is that is this the normal workflow of branch developing in svn, and should the author be me if I was the one committing even if those changes just came from `svn update` or `svn merge`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, why are you the author on the merge? It's not like you committed the changes in the code. Oh, wait a second... Never mind. My bad.

The *author* is always the committer in Subversion. When you do a merge, you're the one who's responsible for verifying that the changes are valid. Even when there are no *merge conflicts* doesn't mean that the merge actually worked. There can be *logic* merge conflicts that the standard merge won't detect, but are just as fatal. This is why the person who does the merge must still test and verify their work.

I normally see this question when people use the *pristine trunk* method of doing work. You're suppose to merge your work to trunk which contains the release code. The developers develop their code on a branch, and the *release engineer* is responsible to move this code to the trunk.

I'm not a fan of this method:

- As you stated, you're now the *blame* for code changes.
- When you do a `svn log`, the log travels down the trunk by default which doesn't tell you anything about the history. All you see is that the release engineer made one change after another.
- Normally, you have the idea that you branch from trunk for each release, but you end up branching for the next release before the previous release is finished which means you normally end up missing bug fixes in the next release that were fixed in the previous release.
- It's a lot of work to remember to merge back to trunk.
- And, it's not even necessary. You *tag* releases, and you can see what was released and compare releases via tags.

I prefer to work off of *trunk* as the main code branch. When you get to a point where you are about to work on multiple releases, you *branch* off of trunk for a release, and you tag your release off of the branch. If you need a bugfix or patch, you have a branch you can use.

This process doesn't eliminate *feature branches*. You don't *have to* develop only on trunk. What it eliminates is the need for a *pristine trunk* which is difficult to maintain and adds practically no value to the development process.

Answer (score 0):

You are author of merge-revision, thus for SVN (inside blame for this revision) you are author of changed strings - blame doesn't perform any retrospective analysis and does not distinguish between merge-commits and ordinary-commits

> is that is this the normal workflow of branch developing in svn

Yes. It is absolutely normal and standard usage of (any) VCS